# Android Studio: Hand Gesture Recognition fatal error: 'ext/atomicity.h' file not found

Tags: android-studio, opencv

So I am trying this app by Eaglesky in Android Studio:
https://github.com/eaglesky/HandGestureApp
but got an error when using right-clicking and choosing ndk-build.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oO9O.png)

I was thinking this might be due to ndk no longer supports gnustl_static so I had to change it to c++_static and eventually got the error.

My Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_ABI := all
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_STL := c++_static
```

My apologize, I'm still quite new to Android Development.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using:
APP_STL := c++_static

OpenCV requires gnuc library:

APP_STL := gnustl_shared

Make sure NDK tool chain is also gnu not clang.